# SQL cumulative sum for each day refresh with new balance for each user

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table and in the table have multiple users and I wonder the total balance of the money for each day.

Each user can make a transaction in a single day and I can see their total balance but I want to see the total amount their balance for the end of each day.

So If I do not join today but yesterday I want to add my tomorrow balance today if I joined yesterday and make a transaction I want to update the balance for the users.

```
SUM(total) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY DATE(time) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) gain,
```

I can make partition but I want to know that I can make this in SQL logically?

```
| Date | User | Balance
+------+------+--------
| Day1 |  A   | 100  
| Day1 |  B   |  50  
| Day1 |  C   | 100
| Day2 |  A   | 150  
| Day2 |  B   |  20 
| Day3 |  E   | 100 
| Day4 |  F   | 200 
| Day5 |  A   |  50 
| Day5 |  F   |  50
```

so

- Day 1  -> A, B, C 250
- Day 2  -> A new 150 , B 20 I know C(100) last balance yesterday so 270
- Day 3  -> E + last other last balance(270) -> 370
- Day 4  -> F + other last balance -> 570
- Day 5  -> A and F changed new balance 320

and so on ..

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting problem! :)

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c9e9ceab47b9f38694a07fe32db9c9bc)

```
SELECT
    the_date,
    SUM(balance)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_date, elems -> 'the_user')
        the_date,
        elems ->> 'the_user' AS the_user,
        (elems ->> 'balance')::int AS balance
    FROM (
        SELECT
            the_date::date AS the_date,
            jsonb_agg(
                row_to_json(mytable)::jsonb
            ) OVER (ORDER BY the_date) as agg
        FROM
           mytable
    ) s,
    jsonb_array_elements(agg) as elems
    ORDER BY the_date, elems -> 'the_user', elems -> 'the_date' DESC
) s
GROUP BY the_date
```

Sketch of the idea:

**1** Aggregating all records cumulatively. (To be able to access each column later, these records are stored as JSON objects in the query).

This yields in

```
date   data       cum_data
Day1   (A:100)    [(A:100)]
Day1   (B:50)     [(A:100),(B:50)],
Day1   (C:100)    [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100)],
Day2   (A:150)    [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100),(A:150)],
Day2   (B:20)     [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100),(A:150),(B:20)]
```

You can see, the last record per day holds all relevant data. The relevant data per user is its very last element within the array.

**2** So, after that you are interested in (1.) the very last record per day and within this (2.) the very last record per user. So, you have to expand the records first:

```
date   cum_data                                  expansion
Day1   [(A:100)]                                 (A:100)
Day1   [(A:100),(B:50)],                         (A:100)
                                                 (B:50)
Day1   [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100)],                 (A:100)     <- last A day1
                                                 (B:50)      <- last B day1
                                                 (C:100)     <- last C day1 
Day2   [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100),(A:150)],         (A:100)
                                                 (B:50)
                                                 (C:100)
                                                 (A:150)
Day2   [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100),(A:150),(B:20)]   (A:100)
                                                 (B:50)
                                                 (C:100)     <- last C day2 (unchanged)
                                                 (A:150)     <- last A day2 (changed)
                                                 (B:20)      <- last B day2 (changed)
```

**3** So, next step is to get the very last occurence of each user per day. This can be done by `DISTINCT ON`, which gets the first record of an ordered group. In your case the group is `(date, user)` and the order is by the user's date `DESC`. The user's date, of course, is stored in the json. So `(A:100)` in fact is `(A:100, day1)` and `(A:150)` is `(A:150, day2)`. The order is by this second element. To get the most recent first, the order needs to be descending, of course.

This yields in

```
date   cum_data                                  expansion
Day1   [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100)],                 (A:100)     <- last A day1
                                                 (B:50)      <- last B day1
                                                 (C:100)     <- last C day1 

Day2   [(A:100),(B:50),(C:100),(A:150),(B:20)]   (C:100)     <- last C day2 (unchanged)
                                                 (A:150)     <- last A day2 (changed)
                                                 (B:20)      <- last B day2 (changed)
```

**4** This finally can be simply grouped and summed up by the `date` column:

```
date  sum
Day1  (A:100) + (B:50) + (C:100) = 250
Day2  (C:100) + (A:150) + (B:20) = 270
```

---

For sure, for large data sets the cumulation would have very low performance. In this case I would recommend writing a simple function which loops through all records; something like this:

```
date list := empty list of (date, balance)
user list := empty list of (user, balance) 

for all records:
    get current date
    if current date <> previous date
       add element (previous date, sum(all balances in user list)) to date list

    get current user
    if current user already exists in user list then
        replace its balance
    else
        add current user to user list

return date list
```

**Edit:** Here's one possible function (which is much faster than the query). It completely follows the given pseudo code. It's just the first throw, I am sure you can optimize the code much, so please see this as sketch as well:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=8ed064c3c741d3b87d3636369c2c767b)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  foobar() RETURNS SETOF record 
AS $$
DECLARE
    _record record;
    _date_rec record;
    _prev_date date;
    _user_balance int;
    _date_balance int;
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE user_recs (the_user text, balance int);

    FOR _record IN 
        SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY the_date
    LOOP
        IF (_prev_date IS NOT NULL AND (_record.the_date::date > _prev_date )) THEN
           SELECT 
               SUM(ur.balance)
           FROM
               user_recs ur
           INTO _date_balance;

           _date_rec = (_prev_date , _date_balance);
           RETURN NEXT _date_rec;
        END IF;

        SELECT balance FROM user_recs ur WHERE ur.the_user = _record.the_user
        INTO _user_balance;

        IF _user_balance IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO user_recs VALUES (_record.the_user, _record.balance);
        ELSE
            UPDATE user_recs ur SET balance = _record.balance WHERE ur.the_user = _record.the_user;
        END IF;

        _prev_date = _record.the_date;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN QUERY
         SELECT 
             _prev_date,
             SUM(ur.balance)::int
         FROM
             user_recs ur;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: @Axis Added explanation

Comment: This is looks great, but I had a mistake that my database is redshift and I could not run. So I will figure out to make with in Redshift. Also I have a question, how efficient that use a table that have more than 100k record?

Comment: As already stated, I believe this could be very slow on huge data sets. That's why I would try the function approach. Later I could create a fiddle to demonstrate. This function should work for Redshift as well

Comment: Definitely your answer deserve it. I would love to run a function in redshift if possible , Thank you all

Comment: Added function.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't run the function in redshift.  Update here soon

Comment: Hm, I have no Redshift for testing, nlthe lowest version I can use for testing is 8.4 (see the fiddle). This works. Maybe you can tell me the problem?

Comment: [42P13][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: create function must specify volatility attribute (IMMUTABLE|STABLE|VOLATILE); this error I am getting everytime

Comment: Does it work if you add VOLATILE? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=a494f3c54bc8fce767b056d38f4df82b

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for cumulative sums on each day, such as this?

```
select user, date_trunc('day', datetimecol),
       sum(total) as daily_total,
       sum(sum(total)) over (partition by user order by date_trunc('day', datetimecol)) as running_total
from t
group by user, date_trunc('day', datetimecol);
```

Comment: Edit the question. Thank you for help

Comment: I made this but if someone does not make any transaction in a single day I do not want to miss it